# Why ggplot2 could not split my plots using facet_grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my data and code:

```
a <- data.frame(Original = c("Full", "Full", "T0", "T0"),
            Classified = c("Full", "T0", "Full", "T0"),
            Value = c(0.69, 0.31, 0.32, 0.68),
            Text = c("69%", "31%", "32%", "68%"))


ggplot(data = a, aes(x=Classified, y=Original, fill=Value)) + 
  geom_tile()+
  geom_text (aes (label=Text), size = 15)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="light blue", high="purple")+
  facet_grid (Original~Classified, space = "free", switch = "y")+
  theme_bw()+
  ggtitle ("ADS")+
  theme (panel.background = element_blank())+
  theme (plot.background = element_blank())+
  theme (panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "white"))+
  ylab ("Percentage of Tokens")+
  theme (strip.text = element_text(size = 23))+
  theme (axis.title = element_text (size = 25))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=25))+
  theme (legend.position = "none")+
  theme (axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

Why it generate sth like the following? It should fully fill the four plots in the four panels.
[image]

Comment: Try to use this for faceting insted of your code `facet_grid (Original~Classified, space = "free", switch = "y", scales = "free")`. Facet grid is using the same scale on all plots and this is the reason you are getting the plot you displayed.

Comment: Exactly, you need to add, scales='free' to facet_grid.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from having `Classified` and `Original` both on your axes and facets. There are two ways to fix this.

- One way to fix this is suggested in the comments by Valter Beaković
  and sandipan, and that is adding `scales = "free"` to the
  `facet_grid`. The axes end up being redundant, since they're just
  giving the same information as the facet labels, so we can remove
  them by adding some more `theme` calls
- Another option would be to **not** call `Classified` and `Original`
  as your `x` and `y`, but instead calling a constant (for example
  `"1"`). Since the axes will be meaningless now, we might as well
  remove them again.

This gives the following code for the first option:

```
ggplot(data = a, aes(x=Classified, y=Original, fill=Value)) + 
  geom_tile()+
  geom_text (aes (label=Text), size = 15)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="light blue", high="purple")+
  facet_grid (Original~Classified, space = "free", switch = "y", scales = "free")+
  theme_bw()+
  ggtitle ("ADS")+
  theme (panel.background = element_blank())+
  theme (plot.background = element_blank())+
  theme (panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "white"))+
  ylab ("Percentage of Tokens")+
  theme (strip.text = element_text(size = 23))+
  theme (axis.title = element_text (size = 25))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=25))+
  theme (legend.position = "none")+
  theme (axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  theme (axis.text = element_blank()) +
  theme (axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

and the following code for the second option:

```
ggplot(data = a, aes(x="1", y="1", fill=Value)) + 
  geom_tile()+
  geom_text (aes (label=Text), size = 15)+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="light blue", high="purple")+
  facet_grid (Original~Classified, space = "free", switch = "y")+
  theme_bw()+
  ggtitle ("ADS")+
  theme (panel.background = element_blank())+
  theme (plot.background = element_blank())+
  theme (panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "white"))+
  ylab ("Percentage of Tokens")+
  theme (strip.text = element_text(size = 23))+
  theme (axis.title = element_text (size = 25))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=25))+
  theme (legend.position = "none")+
  theme (axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
  theme (axis.text = element_blank()) +
  theme (axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

Both result in the same plot:

[image]